# Cassandra Datastax saveQuery with Lightweight Transactions

Tags: java, cassandra

I'm trying to persist an object to cassandra through BatchStatement

```
import com.datastax.driver.mapping.Mapper;

batch.add(mapper.saveQuery(itr.next()));
```

And i want to have **IF NOT EXISTS** clause like

```
INSERT INTO customer_account (customerID, customer_email) 
VALUES (‘LauraS’, ‘lauras@gmail.com’)
IF NOT EXISTS;
```

How should i implement IF NOT EXISTS through saveQuery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately mapping API supports only simple CRUD operations, so light weight transaction is not possible in this context. You can use two ways to work around this:

1. Use mapping Accessors, then your code would looks like 
   accessor interface:

   ```
   @Accessor
   public interface UserAccessor {
       @Query("INSERT INTO sandbox.user (user_id, name) VALUES (:userId, :name) IF NOT EXISTS")
       Statement insertUser(@Param("userId") UUID userId, @Param("name") String name);
   }
   ```

   somewhere in the code:

   ```
   Statement statement = userAccessor.insertUser(user.getUserId(), user.getName());
   ```

   and then you could put statement in the `BatchStatement`
2. Use query builder:

   ```
   Insert insert = new QueryBuilder(cluster).insertInto("sundbox", "user")
           .value("user_id", user.getUserId())
           .value("name", user.getName())
           .ifNotExists();
   ```

   `Insert` is a subtype of `Statement`, so you could put it in the `BatchStatement` as well. Take in to attention, I use Driver 2.2.0, so I use `new QueryBuilder(cluster).insertInto(...` In the case if you use lower driver version, you should use `QueryBuilder.insertInto(...`

Comment: When i m using 'ifNotExists()' in an insert statement i'm seeing error "com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.UnavailableException: Not enough replica available for query at consistency QUORUM (2 required but only 1 alive)" which do not appear on removing ''ifNotExists()''. I'm using datastax driver 2.1.7.

Comment: You need to use accurate replica factor if you use lightweight transaction. Alter 'replication_factor' of keyspace to 1 if you have only one node